# How to use OAuth 2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have what should have been an easy application, that I need to get done. However, [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) 2 is just confusing me. Basically, I need to upload a file or group of files to a [Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_%28company%29), [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29), etc. folder for backup purposes.

I have gone through [SharpBox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/). It seems super easy, but I cannot compile it. There is a missing reference or something that causes it to throw an error:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   "AssemblyAppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.Net40". Check to make sure
>   the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your
>   code.

Also the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'DropBoxCredentials' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As far as I can tell, there aren't any updates. How can fix this problem?

Comment: Though not a full answer, you might want to have a look at http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: If your hell bent on writing your own, I can provide a working example of interacting with facebook server side, which is Oauth2, but it looks like you are already using some custom library I'm not familiar with "AssemblyAppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.Net40".  Also where are you getting this DropBoxCredentials error.  On compile?

Comment: hello, yeah I was kind of hoping to go my own way. the custom lib is        http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/ i am not attached to it, was just the only thing I could find, and it's not working anyhow. It would be nice to see proper oauth code of the auth process.

Comment: @Mattbo, would you happen to have a demonstration of o auth 2 authentication. I have taken a look at the dotnetopenauth.net but being newer to C# I am still a bit lost.

Comment: Hey, I was going to amend my answer to address your other issues, but you must have figured them out.  Let me me know if there is still a problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you are getting is because the library "AssemblyAppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.Net40" can't be found.  Make sure you add it to an available folder, reference it in your project, and include it with the build.  The second error you are getting is because you did not provide the Dropbox OAuth credentials.  You must authenticate the user before making protected requests.  I found this page useful: http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharpBox%20Developer%20Tutorials&referringTitle=Documentation.  Step number 2 details how to authorize with OAuth with DropBox.

OAuth 2 is actually much less complicated than OAuth 1 and it only has a few steps.

1. Use the URL given by the foreign service to generate a complete URL that includes your apps unique consumer key, a redirect URL and any other permissions/properties required by the foreign service.
2. Redirect the user to the URL generated in step 1.  They foreign service will complete its operations and confirm access by your app. If all goes well, you are handed back a unique success token.
3. Make a request to a second location on the foreign service that takes 3 components - Your app's consumer key (like a username), consumer secret (like a password), and the unique request token handed to your app after the successful completion of step 2.  The foreign service takes these three parameters and if step 2 was a success, hands you back a unique token that allows your app to make requests on behalf of this user.  You should store this token as you will need it to make subsequent requests (I like to store the token with the user's foreign service Account Id to make API calls easier).

I can still provide an example of OAuth2.0, but I checked the DropBox docs and their core API says it is still version 1 which is more complicated for a variety of reasons.  In this case, I would recommend sticking with a third party dedicated library that can abstract the messy details.

Comment: hello again, ok I have one more question if you got a second. I can get a oauth_token from dropbox the problem is how can I get it to save to a static location so I can call to it or even save it somewhere. i have pasted what I have below but all it does is open a browser do the auth process then return to the redirect url with the oauth_token.